# Unable to load XML catalog from Gradle

Tags: xml, xslt, ant, gradle, launcher

I'm migrating an ant build file to gradle and have come across this following issue.

The ant build launches a second build file, designating -lib which points to a folder which contains dost.jar & resolver.jar (The code is provided below)

```
<java classname="org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher" fork="true" failonerror="true">
  <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M" />
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="${ant.home}/lib/ant-launcher.jar" />
  </classpath>
  <jvmarg value="-Dant.library.dir=${ant.home}/lib" />
  <arg value="-Djava.awt.headless=true" />
  <arg value="-buildfile" />
  <arg file="build-manual.xml" />
  <arg value="-lib" />
  <arg file="${resource.dir}/lib" />
</java>
```

The task being performed by the launched build file uses a xmlcatalog to run the XSLT task

```
<xslt classpath="${saxon.jar}"
      style="${src.dir}/resources/dita-to-changes.txt.xsl"
      in="${basedir}/manual/dita/topic/something.dita"
      out="${dist.dir}/something.txt">
  <xmlcatalog>
    <catalogpath>
      <path location="${lib.dir}/dita/catalog-dita.xml" />
    </catalogpath>
  </xmlcatalog>
</xslt>
```

I'm trying to forgo launching the task from a launcher and just have the second task run, hence I've created the following task

```
ant.xslt(
    classpath : "$projectDir/lib/misc/saxon9.jar:$projectDir/lib/misc/saxon9-dom.jar:
    $projectDir/lib/misc/saxon9-ant.jar:$resource.dir/lib/resolver.jar", 
        basedir : "manual/dita", style : "$ditaLib/custom/dita2html.xsl", destdir : "$manualBuild") {
    param(name: "versionname", expression : versionName)
    xmlcatalog {
        catalogpath {
            path(location: "$ditaLib/catalog-dita.xml")
        }
    }
}
```

Which falis with the following error

```
[ant:xslt] Loading stylesheet .....\lib\dita\custom\dita2html.xsl
Warning: XML resolver not found; external catalogs will be ignored
[ant:xslt] : Fatal Error! java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...\concept\concept.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified) Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...\concept\concept.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

It seems that somehow the resolver isn't found even though it's in the classpath.

Please not that the same issue occurs when I launch the second ant task independently